# Surjective homomorphism of Lie algebras implies surjective homomorphism of the Lie Algebra of the maximal compact subgroup

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I tried it before, here is another try.
We have commutative Lie-groups $H$ and $G$ and a Lie-group hom. $f: G \rightarrow H$ such that the corresponding map of Lie-algebras $df: L(G) \rightarrow L(H)$ is surjective. Furthermore $H$ is compact. Let $G^1$ be the maximal compact subgroup of $G$. I want to show that the map of Lie-algebras $df: L(G^1) \rightarrow L(H)$ is also surjective. Can this be true? I am not so familiar with that kind of arguments, sorry.

Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 3):

This is false. Take $G = \mathbb{R}, H = S^1$ and $f : \mathbb{R} \to S^1$ to be the exponential map. $df$ is an isomorphism and $H$ is compact. But $G$ has trivial maximal compact subgroup.